# Does a creature suffer any other disability if its speed is reduced to 0?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

If a creature has a movement speed of 0, does it impose any other effects?

My idea is that prone does, so why shouldn't immobility

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're asking? Having a movement of 0 does have mechanical effects on game actions/abilities based on movement. The list can be extensive - is there something specific you're looking into?

Comment: How did the creature's speed get to zero? Things that reduce speed enough to get it to zero would probably have additional effects.

Answer (score 5):

### No

Prone does because the rules say it does. 0 movement doesn't because the rules give it no effect.